# AFNetworkActivirty logger swift 3.0 xcode 8 doesn't log anything

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, afnetworking

I am using this code for logging afnetwork activity

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let consoleLogger = AFNetworkActivityConsoleLogger()
        consoleLogger.level = .AFLoggerLevelDebug
        AFNetworkActivityLogger.shared().addLogger(consoleLogger)
        AFNetworkActivityLogger.shared().startLogging() 
        return true
    }
```

but my console log is empty

pods :

```
pod 'AFNetworking','3.0'
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', git: 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', branch: '3_0_0'
```

also disabled trash for log in xcode 8 
http://prntscr.com/d1p4r7

before this, log worked but format of output json was some kind of strange, and any parse services, like http://json.parser.online.fr  could not recognize it as valid json

please, give me some advice or solution for this two problems. thank you

P.S. using AfNetrowk due low version of iOS that is needed to be supported.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code on a project of mine and it worked.

Normally I use it differently as follows:

```
if let logger = AFNetworkActivityLogger.shared().loggers.first as? AFNetworkActivityLoggerProtocol {
   logger.level = .AFLoggerLevelDebug
}

AFNetworkActivityLogger.shared().startLogging()
```

I also checked some other [sources/tutorials](https://medium.com/@rizwanm/network-activity-logger-for-afnetworking-3-0-ccf59590a3f5#.g6fn1jcnb) and I do not see anything wrong with the code you presented. Can it be that no request is being done using AFNetworking?